# python Django model indentation error

Tags: python, django, indentation

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
        description = models.TextField()

        class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

        def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am getting this error

> ```
> verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
>                   ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block
> ```

I am using gedit with use spaces as option for tabs ( also tried altering tab width)..I am almost certain that the code is correct..but some problem with spacing and tabs..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
```

You are not indenting correctly after `class Meta:`.

Answer (score 3):

it should be

```
    from django.db import models

    class Category(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
        description = models.TextField()

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

Since `verbose_name_plural` is expected to be in `class Meta`, it should be idented.